# SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output on Windows 10

Tags: solidity, python, solc

I was previously working on windows 8.1 but recently upgraded to windows 10 so I could use the Ganache GUI. The code seemed to work absolutely fine for windows 8.1 but I cannot seem to install solc on windows 10.

**Here's my code:**

```
import json

from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
simple_storage_file = file.read()

print("Installing...")
install_solc("0.6.0")

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
{
"language": "solidity",
"sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
"settings": {
"outputSelection": {
"": {
"": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
}
}
},
},
solc_version="0.6.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
"bytecode"
]["object"]

abi = json.loads(
compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["metadata"]
)["output"]["abi"]

print(compiled_sol)
```

**Here's the error that shows up:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 633, in _validate_installation
installed_version = wrapper._get_solc_version(binary_path)
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\wrapper.py", line 17, in _get_solc_version
stdout_data = subprocess.check_output([str(solc_binary), "--version"], encoding="utf8")
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\.solcx\solc-v0.6.0\solc.exe', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 3221225595.

During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 13, in
install_solc("0.6.0")
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 466, in install_solc
raise exc
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 459, in install_solc
_validate_installation(version, solcx_binary_path)
File "C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 636, in _validate_installation
raise SolcInstallationError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output.
```

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the command 'C:\Users\BIG BOSS MULTIMEDIA.solcx\solc-v0.6.0\solc.exe --version' returned an error(or an unexpected status), it might be an issue with that solc executable. You can try navigating to that directory, delete the entire '\solc-v0.6.0' folder and try installing it again.